# How to insert a table consist of several dictionaries into MySQL tables?

Tags: python, mysql

I have the below result from my python code:

```
[

 {filename:'1,2',Name:'Gorge',registration number: '6657', registration date: '2012-09-10 14:31:13'}, 
 {filename:'5,43',Name:'mazu',registration number:'45', registration date:'2012-10-08 17:28:47'}]
```

and as soon as I want to put it in a MySQL table, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jio\Datasets 1\MyTable_info.py", line 63, in <module>
    cur.executemany(query,records)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 243, in executemany
    self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, msg.args[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

My python code to insert the result in MySQL table is the below code:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(host = "******", port=***, user = "***", passwd="*****", db="****")
with con:
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info(id INT(10) auto_increment primary key,file_name VARCHAR(10), 
Name VARCHAR(50),Registration ID INT(50),registration time INT(50))''')


    query= "INSERT INTO info (file_name, Name, Registration ID, registration time) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s )"
    cur.executemany(query,records)

    con.commit()
```

Does anyone has an idea why I get this error and what does the error mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert a String into a field INT(50).

Take a look in the last field of the table, registration time field. It is an Integer and you are trying to insert values like '2012-10-08 17:28:47' or '2012-09-10 14:31:13'.

For a quick fix just change registration time field type as a VARCHAR(50).

But maybe, for perfomance issues, you should think to use some kind of TIMESTAMP field instead of a VARCHAR for this kind of purposes.

---

Apart from don't use INT type for field where you would like to add some kind of String.

Modify the records variable from

[ {filename:'1,2',Name:'Gorge',registration number: '6657', registration date: '2012-09-10 14:31:13'}, 
 {filename:'5,43',Name:'mazu',registration number:'45', registration date:'2012-10-08 17:28:47'}]

to
[('1,2','Gorge','6657', '2012-09-10 14:31:13'),('5,43','mazu','45','2012-10-08 17:28:47')]

And avoid use whitespaces for the columns names as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote field names. What the contents of records?

Comment: The records content is what I have paste above as the results. There are one of those for each file. I am browsing a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces in field names.

If you are required to, quote them with the ` character.

Comment: Post it here. 99% of the time it will be because you used spaces in your field names, so don't.

Comment: I cannot beacuse I am extracting the keys for my dictionary from files, and the keys over there are like this